# How to make working radio buttons in angular-formly?

Tags: radio-button, angular6, angular-formly

I am making a form with angular-formly where I use radio-buttons. The problem is that for some reason the radio-button-group does not seem to update its value or update the value to the formly model.

Example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formly-ggobzt

Any advices how can I get the radio buttons working? Thanks.

Comment: pass `key` instead of `id`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formly-9b7mk8 in `v5` you can customize it using `valueProp`

Comment: Big thanks!! Would give you two thumbs if I could.